# Using unspecified std::_ARRAY in structs after VC++2005

Tags: c++, struct, sizeof, visual-c++-2005, valarray

I am migrating an old project up to be compiled in newer versions of Visual Studio.
I am getting a compiler error C4430 while compiling an old struct:

```
struct SHOP_ITEM_LIST
{
char title[50];
char description[200];
_ARRAY(SHOP_ITEM);     // Another Struct with some integer and char array values
};
```

I researched that error and made out that since VC++2005, missing type specifiers aren't allowed anymore. It's not being interpreted as integer anymore.

I am not familiar with std::_Array< _Tp > and dont know how it behaves when being used in a struct with sizeof().
Would `int _ARRAY(SHOP_ITEM);` just do the trick, or would it manipulate the size of the struct?

What is the proper way to upgrade this struct to VC++2005 and later?

Comment: wow that is an _old_ compiler

Comment: Yeah it is. VC++6  :S Thats why I want to upgrade it as soon as possible

Comment: What is `_ARRAY`?  I've never seen it before.

Answer (score 0):

It won't work if you put another type like `int` in front of it. It also won't work if you simple replace it with a template like `std::_Array`. It's clear from the context that `_ARRAY` was a macro.

I don't believe the definition for `_ARRAY` was provided by your Visual C++ 6 compiler. You should try to find out where it comes from. The simple fix may be to just include the file that defines it.

Failing that then the `_ARRAY` macro was probably defined either something like this:

```
#define _ARRAY(type) type _array_##type[1]
```

or like this:

```
#define _ARRAY(type) type *_array_##type
```

There should also be other macros that your code uses to do allocations and to access elements of the shop item array. Do you see other identifiers similar `_ARRAY` in your code?  They wouldn't necessarily generate compile time errors, as they would probably look like undeclared functions to the compiler, however you'll need to implement them as well.

Comment: Yeah there are other definitions like that in the project. But they sit in header files. I could not find a typedef or smth similar for _ARRAY in the whole solution. Also searching for the Definition of _ARRAY leads to nothing, and just highlights every _ARRAY in the code. So I researched the type and got this link (http://www.aoc.nrao.edu/php/tjuerges/ALMA/STL/html-4.1.2/structstd_1_1__Array.html). So I assume its the std::_ARRAY, but its kind of strange... I am not so familiar with C++ yet, and hoped it was a well known type :s

Comment: No, it's not the `std::_Array` template you linked. As said it's a macro, a preprocessor macro created with a `#define` preprocessor directive.  Something like one of the two examples I gave above.

Comment: It really is funny... The project was not changed at all. Just migrated from VC++6 to VC++2008 for a test, if it works. VC++6 compiles without a singe error, but doesnt finds the definition of _ARRAY either. VC++2008 says it cant compile because unspecified types are deprecated, but would compile with an "int" in front of it. It also cant find the definition of _ARRAY.... I will hang on searching for this in header files and if I dont succeed, I will have to rework every struct to use normal arrays...

Comment: @user2334932: VC++6 too can stop compilation after preprocessing. That would allow you to verify whether `_ARRAY` is a macro, and if so, what it expands to.

Comment: @MSalters that sounds great. Where does the preprocessor give some information about macros, and where they are expanded from? I see that I can stop compilations with #error, but I'm not sure if thats the thing which you have mentioned.